# How to create blocks from shortcodes?

Tags: shortcode, block-editor

I want to create a shortcode of myself that outputs “blocks”.

#### Level 1: Setting a pure text

I know how to do a simple shortcode. Let’s take this example.

```
add_shortcode( 'greet', 'myNiceShortCode' );
function myNiceShortCode( array $attributes )
{
    // Process attributes
    $result = "Hello, world!";
    return $result;
}
```

If I set then `[greet volume="loud"]` I see `Hello, world!` in its place.

#### Level 2: Outputting HTML

I see I can output HTML there:

```
$result = "<h2>Hello, world!</h2>";
```

I can see the `Hello, world!` as an `<h2>` in the page or post.

#### Level 3: My Question: How can I now output “full blocks”?

Now I want something more advanced:

I want the shortcode to output “full blocks” the same than those I could add manually. Say I want to add a full gallery block with photos being:

```
$data = [
    [
        // ????? What other things?
        "image" => ???? whatever to get "image-1.jpg" from the gallery,
    ],
    [
        // ????? What other things?
        "image" => ???? whatever to get "image-2.jpg" from the gallery,
    ],
];

$result = ?????? function of $data;
```

I mean: I know I want those 2 photos. I don’t want to spit “pure html” as then I loose all the magic of working with the block system (responsiveness, using the theme defaults, etc.) so I want just to spit out the gallery “as if I set it manually”, but all automagically outputted from my short-code.

I don’t want to print `<div><img ...><img ...></div>` but the gallery block itself.

#### Question

How can I output “something” that means “here this is not pure HTML, this is a block” to the rendering loop?

Answer (score 0):

> I want the shortcode to output “full blocks”

This is the wrong approach, instead you want a block that outputs a shortcode.

Specifically, a block that is rendered via PHP. Once you know how to do that it becomes as trivial as calling `do_shortcode` and inserting block attributes into the shortcode by crafting it, e.g. something like this:

```php
do_shortcode( '[myshortcode attribute1="' . $attribute1 . "]' );
```

Although in your case it's usually easier to call the function that implements the shortcode directly.

You can specify a PHP file to render your block in `block.json` that you can call your shortcode in. You should not need a save component in your block, and you can use a server side renderer in your edit component to display the result of your shortcode in the block editor.

Once you've done this, you can ignore shortcodes and deal entirely with standard blocks and standard solutions to block problems.

Comment: I don't really get how to start. Suppose that in a page I will have a content where I want to display either a quizz or an image in function of the following: a) If the article has a quizz of certain type associated with it, show the blocks that compose the quizz. b) If the article does not have a quizz associated, display an image. I thought setting a `[quizz_or_image]` shortcode that prints whatever needed. Just to make sure: Are you telling me that it's better to create a custom block named "quizz_or_image" and set the block in that place?

Comment: the idea that you can insert blocks using a shortcode is not a thing. The idea that you can insert shortcodes using a block on the other hand is very much a thing, and even has a dedicated shortcode block. As I mentioned though, a shortcode just tells WP _"when you see `[quizz_or_image]` call this function and replace it with what the function returns"_, nothing prevents you having a block that has a render function that does the same thing. It's a major mistake to use shortcodes as the starting point

Comment: This does require you to insert a block into your content though, which isn't much different to shortcodes since you need to insert shortcodes into your content to use them. the difference is that you can then declare the block has inner blocks and then insert anything inside using the editor, you can't do that with shortcodes unless you want to type all the HTML out by hand ( and if you built a block why bother with a shortcode anyway )

Comment: It may be helpful to know that there is a `do_blocks` equivalent to `do_shortcode`, but, why ask WP to parse and process a shortcode to call a function when you can call the function directly and skip the middle steps? Also the canonical solution if you want to put something at the top of every post is to modify the template. E.g. put the block in the single post template, not the post content. `do_blocks` could do that for you, or maybe in WP 6.4 block hooks. Eitherway your research will very quickly hit a dead end if you try to put blocks inside shortcodes

Comment: Thanks Tom. I don't really need to place the contents "in the editor". I'm happy to put them programmatically. In fact I *want* to do it programmatically. I don't pretend to build a static web, all the opposite, I want the content to be fully managed by a bot. Although I could "print" pure HTML I was looking for a simple way to "print existing blocks". Not printing blocks selected in the UX, but let the bot select what "blocks" to output. I think building a block of my own is much more complex than creating a tag-parser. Let me reformulate: May I "print existing blocks" at will?

Comment: yes, `do_blocks` works the same was as `do_shortcode`, you can create a block, copy paste it into a string and pass that string to that function. It takes raw block markup and prints out rendered blocks